# Internal Name Resolution

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, active-directory

We recently migrated our work environment from a Server 2003 server running Active Directory, DNS, and DHCP to Server 2008.  When we did this, something got messed up and now I can't join a machine to the domain without referencing the fully qualified domain name.  so, where I used to be able to just say that a machine was part of FOO, I now have to FOO.BAR.COM.

I suspect DNS is the culprit, but I'm not entirely sure. Any suggestions on correcting my setup is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Either (a) you need WINS or (b) your DHCP needs to set the DNS suffix to the domain name.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe override this locally by specifying a default search domain in your network setup.

Answer (score 0):

if you have more than 1 network scope and no WINS - you have to use FQDN.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that the clients aren't properly appending the domain when performing requests.  The first fix would be for configuring the DHCP server to hand out the appropriate DNS suffixes.

You can also force it manually on a client by going to the properties of the network interface -> highlight Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4) -> Properties -> Advanced -> switch to the DNS tab -> and choosing the "Append these DNS suffixes (in order)" and adding the appropriate suffixes, in this case "BAR.COM".  Then trying to connect to "FOO" will automatically be resolved to FOO.BAR.COM when it attempts to make the request.